# How can i change AVPlayer Video Quality while playing

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, avplayer, videoquality

I used [this](https://github.com/DZamataev/DZVideoPlayerViewController) library for playing video from `URL`, and I am able to play video.

Now I want to change the currently playing video quality like **(low, medium, high)**.

Library uses AVPlayer and how can i change quality with AVPlayer?

I listen about **preferred​Peak​Bit​Rate** but I have no idea about it.

Please help me how can i do that?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot set video quality directly on the `AVPlayer`, however, you can do this by accessing `videoComposition` property on `AVPlayerItem` which is then supplied to `AVPlayer` (via for example `replaceCurrentItem:` method or on AVPlayer initialization). So:

1. Create or get you `AVPlayerItem`'s `AVVideoComposition` instance, and set it's `frameDuration`, `renderSize` and `renderScale` properties. Take a look in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avvideocomposition) for more info.
2. Set it to your "movie" `videoComposition` property, `AVPlayerItem` instance (again, look in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem) for details).
3. Play that in your player.

If you want to do this on the fly while playing movie, adjustments of time for player item should be done I guess.

Comment: can you help me with demo code. like how can i achieve that?

Comment: I suggest that you should update your question with your solution attempt (code) based on information I provided for you and then maybe can help you more. SO is not "free code" site, at least try to learn.

Comment: If i use this way to change resolution too lower size, will it help to save memory?

Comment: @FrankCheng probably, you can check it by running your app and looking at memory consumption in top-left corner of the Xcode interface (where? check this awesome graphic: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1200/1*ygeMI3iHCHnWVlbz_z8qvA.png), and voilaszek!:)